# Dynamically adding a scroll view above the view iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created a UIView through code  and want to add some images and description on that view.For that purpose i wished to add a scroll view so that we can user can scroll down to see the images and description.Can anyone help me how to add a scroll view above a  UIView through code.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try this:-

```
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
    scrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    [scrollView setDelegate:self];
    [scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];    
    [[self view] addSubview:scrollView];

Now set the content size of scroll view:-

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 600);//put values according to your requirements.
```

Comment: Thanku.but im getting an error"incompatible type of argument 1 of 'initWithFrame'.and one warning "method view not found(return type defaults to id)".can you help me to solve this

Comment: Is your class in which you are adding this is of UIViewController type or UIView type.

Comment: scrollView = [(UIScrollView *)[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)]; i done this to remove error \

Comment: [self addSubview:scrollView]; this for removing warning

Answer (score 0):

```
UIScrollView *newView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollFrame];
   [newView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
   [newView setDelegate:self];
   [newView setBackgroundColor:backgroundColor];
   [newView setPagingEnabled:YES];
   [newView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
   [newView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];

   [[self view] addSubview:newView];
```

you can set Frame In place of scrollFrame.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Actually you probably don't want to create a UIView, you should create a UIScrollView then add the images and that as subviews of the UIScrollView.  Then you'll have everything scrolling.  You'll then set up the UIScrollView the way you want it to be.